# Joint uniform distribution two different intervals

Tags: probability, statistics, uniform-distribution

I have a problem with the following exercise:

**X corresponds to the duration of Paul’s commute to work, and Y to the duration of Peter’s. X is uniformly distributed in [15, 25] and Y in [15, 30]. X and Y are assumed
to be independent.
What is the probability that Peter and Paul both take more than 20 minutes to get
to work?**

Everything I know is that I have to use the joint probability density function.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

> "Everything I know is that I have to use the joint probability density function..."

The independence of $X$ and $Y$ tells you the opposite.

You are asked to find: $$P(X>20,Y>20)$$ where $\{X>20\}$ and $\{Y>20\}$ are independent events.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Now I'm totally unsure how I should proceed. I was thinking about using double integrals from '20 till infinity'....

Comment: Can find $P(X>20)$ and $P(Y>20)$ separately? Then multiplication of these results gives you the answer on base of independence.